# не могу получить значение ячейки в QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt

имеется таблица,необходимо было сделать ввод в ячейки только double:

```
m_doubleValidator.setNotation(QDoubleValidator::StandardNotation); //стандартная нотация
for (int j = 1; j < ui->SG_Uvn->columnCount(); j++)
    for (int i = 1; i <= ui->SG_Uvn->rowCount(); i++) {
        QLineEdit * tableline = new QLineEdit;
        tableline->setValidator( &m_doubleValidator );
        ui->SG_Uvn->setCellWidget(j, i, tableline);
    }
```

Дальше я пытался получить значение ячейки так :

```
SG_Current->item(i, j)->text();
```

Но т.к ячейка пустая(хотя в форме она заполнена) вылетает ошибка.
Я понимаю что теперь в ячейки таблицы у меня находится не QTableWidgetItem, а QLineEdit.

Так вот как же теперь получить значение этого QLineEdit?

Comment: SG_Current = ui->SG_Uvn;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо делать симметрично.

Установить:

```
QLineEdit* edt = new QLineEdit();
//...
tableWidget->setCellWidget(row, column, edt)
```

Получить:

```
QLineEdit* w = qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(tableWidget->cellWidget(row, col));
if( w != Q_NULLPTR ) {
    w->text();
}
```